# "Steven Pyles" is unfortunate name?

Tags: names

A: DV8’s real name is Steven Pyles. Unfortunate name.

I heard this line from CSI episode.
I thought Steven is very common name.
So, is Pyles strange first name in the US?
Or, is "Steven Pyles" unusual combination?

(I searched this name on Google and there is one chief names Steven Pyles though.)

Comment: Pyles is a homonym of piles, which is a medical condition also known as haemorrhoids.

Answer (score 1):

Steve Pyles or Steven Pyles is 2 jokes. Either...

Piles, which is a painful medical condition involving someones bum. Bums are almost always funny.

Or...

Steve piles is a grammar joke, being an incomplete sentence, like "Steve piles papers"

Its unusual in English both a) that a name makes a sentence, and b) that a name means anything else other than a name. The secret to humour is surprise, so....

Comment: I think it's your first explanation personally